# It seems it doesn't save cropped images

Tags: python, opencv

i am newbie to python.

Currently i'm struggle with cv2 problem.

Code is

```
import cv2, os, glob
import numpy as np
min_dist = 30
min_r = 15
max_r = 27
hough_ksize = 2.0
w,h = 60,60
#traindata_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "images\\cropped\\testdata")
traindata_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "images\\cropped\\traindata")
os.chdir("images/screenshots")
images = glob.glob("*.png")
numberofphotos = int((open("../cropped/labeldata.txt", "r").read()))
print(numberofphotos)
total = 0
last_img_name = None
img_path = None
for _img in images:
    print(_img)
    img = cv2.imread(_img, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, hough_ksize, min_dist, minRadius=min_r, 
maxRadius=max_r)
    if circles is not None:
        circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")
        for (x, y, r) in circles:
            cropped = img[max(0,int(y-h/2)):int(y+h/2), max(0,int(x-w/2)):int(x+w/2)]
            cv2.imshow("", cropped)
            dt = cv2.waitKeyEx(0)
            if dt == 2490368:
                cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(traindata_path, "up", "%d.png"%(numberofphotos+total+1)), cropped)
                print(os.path.join(traindata_path, "up", "%d.png"%(numberofphotos+total+1)))
                total += 1
                img_path = "up"
            elif dt == 2621440:
                cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(traindata_path, "down", "%d.png" % (numberofphotos + total + 1)), cropped)
                print(os.path.join(traindata_path, "down", "%d.png"%(numberofphotos+total+1)))
                total += 1
                img_path = "down"
            elif dt == 2424832:
                cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(traindata_path, "left", "%d.png" % (numberofphotos + total + 1)), cropped)
                print(os.path.join(traindata_path, "left", "%d.png"%(numberofphotos+total+1)))
                total += 1
                img_path = "left"
            elif dt == 2555904:
                cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(traindata_path, "right", "%d.png" % (numberofphotos + total + 1)), cropped)
                print(os.path.join(traindata_path, "right", "%d.png"%(numberofphotos+total+1)))
                total += 1
                img_path = "right"
            else:
                pass
with open("../cropped/labeldata.txt", "w") as b:
    b.write(str(numberofphotos+total))
print("added %d new images"%(total))
```

It is working corretly.

But it doesn't save cropped image at cropped/traindata.

I want to saved the croppeed images into up, down, right, left folders.

what should i have to do.

Comment: I see in your code that you are not creating the directory `cropped/traindata`. OpenCV when saving the image to a specific location assumes that the directory already exists. If the directory doesn't exist, it wont save the image. I would suggest to keep a conditional to create `cropped/traindata` if it doesn't exist before the for loop.

Comment: Hmm,,, eventhough i create cropped/traindata folder, it still doesn't work. @SriRaghuMalireddi

Comment: Your traindata_path is `cropped/traindata` but you are also assuming there are four subfolders under `traindata`. For example, `os.path.join(traindata_path, "up", "%d.png"%(numberofphotos+total+1)` - this statement is saying OpenCV to save at `cropped/traindata/up`. The folder up is not created in the first place.

Comment: okay i will gonna try. thanks :) @SriRaghuMalireddi

Comment: what i have to do if even i made 4 folders under cropped still doesn't work? @SriRaghuMalireddi

Comment: after i reboot the computer, it works well. :) thank you so much for help @SriRaghuMalireddi